What kind of figures are insightful in game theory?
I am finishing my thesis on a signalling model in which I characterize the perfect bayesian equilibria of the game. However, I find that my final expressions are too mathematical and that the intuition behind them is not so visual in their current form. I would like to sample the distributions and choose values for the parameters to observe what happens and which equilibrium appears but I cannot imagine what kind of figures I could use to do so.
Do you have any advice or examples of applied-theory papers where they use some figures that truly help to understand the mechanisms in play ?
Thank you !

Can you provide a bit more context? What figures you ought to use depend heavily on the results you find, whether you have unique equilbria, etc.

Yes, the model is in sustainable finance. The game considers a firm who has set a net-zero target, there are 4 types of firms, depending on the value of a short-termism parameter of the CEO, and of the efficiency of the firm. There is uncertainty about the final value since a more efficient firm will have a higher value after reaching net-zero. The actions of the firm, are announcement of an interim-target and investing towards reaching the target. A short-termist CEO could announce the target and then green-wash if the green-washing penalties are not high enough.

Are these firms operating via a value function maximization type of process? If so, I think it would be interested to show some sort of reservation value for which they are indifferent between green washing and not? Im assuming this is finite time horizon?

Also any sensitivity analysis is good. What happens to this reservation value or the amount of green-washing as you vary the short-termism parameter (I guess this amounts to just showing your 4 types). You could also show how the efficiency draws matter (I am assuming it is stochastic). Are your 4 types high/low combinations of short-termism and efficiency? You could also vary each of them continuously and plot the results.
